# CheckBox ".Checked" property returning as "false" even when the checkbox is checked

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

So I have a VS form that has a bunch of checkboxes in a groupbox, and I have a foreach loop that is supposed to go through each checkbox in the groupbox and see whether or not the checkbox is checked. Here is the code:

```
float TopPr = 0;

            foreach (CheckBox c in grpOrderToppings.Controls) 
            {                                                
                CheckBox chkbox = c as CheckBox;
                if (chkbox.Checked == true)
                {
                    topCount += 1;
                }
            }
```

The problem I'm having is that "chkbox.Checked" is returning "false" for checkboxes that are actually checked.

EDIT: Here's all my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;


namespace MaxsPizzaShop
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const float fltTax = .075f; //class-level variable
        public const Single sngSmallPr = 8.0f;
        public const Single sngRegPr = 10.0f;
        public const Single sngLrgPr = 12.0f;
        public const Single sngTopPr = 1.0f;
        public Single sngPrice = 0.0f;
        public Single sngCost = 0.0f;
        public Single sngQuantity = 1;
        public Single sngTax = 0.0f;
        public bool bNameValid = false;
        public bool bPhoneValid = false;
        public bool bAddr1Valid = false;
        public bool bCityValid = false;
        public bool bZipValid = false;


        //bool bPayValid = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnOrder.Enabled = false;
            btnOrder.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            btnOrder.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblInvalidDataWarning.Visible = true;
            radSizeReg.Checked = true;
            chkTopChe.Checked = true;
            sngQuantity = 1;
            cbState.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "StateAbbrev.txt")).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray());
            //Above this comment is a way to import the contents of a .txt list into a ComboBox's option-list, found via StackOverflow. It appears to work decently.
            cbState.Text = "MN";
            cbPayMethod.Text = "[SELECT]";

        }

        public void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) //check for valid data after every key press
        {

        }

        private void btnOrder_EnabledChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnOrder.Enabled == false)
            {
                ttAccept.ToolTipTitle = "Please enter all info before ordering.";
                ttAccept.SetToolTip(btnOrder, "You have not filled-out all of the neccesary info to order. If you are having issues with this app, please contact the developer.");
            }
            if (btnOrder.Enabled == true)
            {
                ttAccept.ToolTipTitle = "Order your Pizza Now!";
                ttAccept.SetToolTip(btnOrder, "It will come in about an hour!");
            }
        }

        private void txtCustName_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar >= 65 && e.KeyChar <= 90) //allow A-Z uppercase
            { }
            else if (e.KeyChar >= 97 && e.KeyChar <= 122) //allow a-z lowercase
            { }
            else if (e.KeyChar == 8) //allow backspace
            { }
            else if (e.KeyChar == 32) //allow space
            { }
            //else if (e.KeyChar )

            else
            { e.Handled = true; }
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //reset user info
            txtCustName.Clear();
            mtbCustPhone.Clear();
            txtAddressOne.Clear();
            txtAddressTwo.Clear();
            txtCity.Clear();
            mtbZip.Clear();
            sngQuantity = 1;

            foreach (Control c in grpOrderToppings.Controls) //This is a for-loop that clears every topping checkbox when the "Clear" button is clicked
            {
                CheckBox chkbox = c as CheckBox;
                if (chkbox.Name != "chkTopChe" && chkbox.Checked)
                {
                    chkbox.Checked = false; //This is supposed to Un-Check any checkbox the loop finds checked.
                }
            }
            chkTopChe.Checked = true; //re-check cheese topping

            //reset payment info
            cbPayMethod.Text = "[SELECT]";
            mtbPayCardCode.Clear();

            btnOrder.Enabled = false;
            bNameValid = false;
            bPhoneValid = false;
            bAddr1Valid = false;
            bCityValid = false;
            bZipValid = false;

        }

        private void btnOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnOrder.Enabled == true)
            {
                string CustInfo = "";

                Payment pizza = new Payment();
                //sngCost = pizza.CalcPay();

                MessageBox.Show("Pizza Ordered. Total payment due is: " + sngCost);

                Customer objCust = new Customer(txtCustName.Text, mtbCustPhone.Text, txtAddressOne.Text, txtAddressTwo.Text, txtCity.Text, cbState.Text, mtbZip.Text);
                CustInfo = ("\n" + objCust.CustNameProp + " | " + objCust.CustPhoneProp + " | " + objCust.CustAddr1Prop + " | " + objCust.CustAddr2Prop +
                    " | " + objCust.CustCityProp + " | " + objCust.CustStateProp + " | " + objCust.CustZipProp);

                MessageBox.Show("Does this info look correct?" + CustInfo);



                //CREATE TRANSACTION LOG 
                string strLog = Application.StartupPath + "/../../TransLog.txt";
                FileStream fslog = new FileStream(strLog, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
                StreamWriter swLog = new StreamWriter(fslog);

                // TODO: Update this WriteLine output format for database compatability.
                // TODO: Make 
                swLog.WriteLine(txtCustName.Text + "\t" + lblDateTime.Text + CustInfo + "\n" + sngCost + "\n" + "------------------------------------");

                swLog.Close();

                //END CREATE TRANSACTION LOG
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }


        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dlgResult;
            dlgResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to close? You will lose your order progress!", "Close and cancel order?",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);

            if (dlgResult == DialogResult.Yes) // Closes program if user clicked yes
            {
                this.Close();
            }

        }

        private void btnPrice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // CHANGED TO PUBLIC
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            Payment payment = new Payment();
            Single sngCost = payment.CalcPay(worker, e);
            e.Result = sngCost;

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); // Don't forget to sleep!
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (1 == 1)// btnOrder.Enabled == true
            {

                Payment payment = new Payment();
                string strPizzaSize = payment.PizzaSize("size");
                string strSumTotal = e.Result.ToString();

                DialogResult resPriceBox = MessageBox.Show(strPizzaSize + " Pizza Selected. The Total Price: " + strSumTotal); //Print out the price after calculation

                //RESET PRICE VALUES so that they don't add up when the user presses the "Price" button more than once.
                if (resPriceBox == DialogResult.OK || resPriceBox == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    //sngPrice = 0.0f;
                    //topCount = 0.0f;
                }
            }
        }

        private void timDateTimeTicker_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblDateTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + "  |  " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }


        public void nudQuantity_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sngQuantity = (float)nudQuantity.Value; //Are you SURE this needs to be a float?
        }

        public void nudQuantity_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sngQuantity = (float)nudQuantity.Value;
        }



        private void cbPayMethod_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cbPayMethod.Text == "American Express")
            {
                mtbPayCardCode.Visible = true; //show the card code box once the user selected a pay method.
                lblCardNum.Visible = true; //show the card number label, too.
                mtbPayCardCode.Mask = "9999-999999-99999";
            }
            else if (cbPayMethod.Text == "Visa" || cbPayMethod.Text == "Mastercard")
            {
                mtbPayCardCode.Visible = true; //show the card code box once the user selected a pay method.
                lblCardNum.Visible = true; //show the card number label, too.
                mtbPayCardCode.Mask = "9999-9999-9999-9999";
            }
            else if (cbPayMethod.Text == "Cash" || cbPayMethod.Text == "Check")
            {
                mtbPayCardCode.Visible = false; //hide the card code box if the user selects "cash" or "check".
                MessageBox.Show("You have chosen 'cash' or 'check' as your payment method. Remember to have this physical payment method ready for exchange for when the pizza man arrives.");
            }
        }


        public void txtCustName_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) //changed "private" to "public"
        {
            if (txtCustName.Text.Length > 4)
            {
                //e.Cancel = false;
                bNameValid = true;
                txtCustName.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                //e.Cancel = true;
                bNameValid = false;
                txtCustName.ForeColor = Color.Red;

            }
        }

        public void mtbCustPhone_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) //changed "private" to "public"
        {
            if (mtbCustPhone.MaskCompleted == true)
            {
                //e.Cancel = false;
                bPhoneValid = true;
                mtbCustPhone.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                //e.Cancel = true;
                bPhoneValid = false;
                mtbCustPhone.ForeColor = Color.Red;

            }
        }


        public void txtAddressOne_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtAddressOne.Text.Length > 4)
            {
                //e.Cancel = false;
                bAddr1Valid = true;
                txtAddressOne.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                //e.Cancel = true;
                bAddr1Valid = false;
                txtAddressOne.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }

        public void txtCity_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtCity.Text.Length > 1)
            {
                //e.Cancel = false;
                bCityValid = true;
                txtCity.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                //e.Cancel = true;
                bCityValid = false;
                txtCity.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }

        public void mtbZip_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mtbZip.MaskFull == true)
            {
                //e.Cancel = false;
                bZipValid = true;
                mtbZip.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                //e.Cancel = true;
                bZipValid = false;
                mtbZip.ForeColor = Color.Red;

            }
        }

        private void btnUpdateInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bNameValid == true && bPhoneValid == true && bAddr1Valid == true && bCityValid == true && bZipValid == true) // && bPayValid == true <-- TODO: Set up "bPayValid" 
            {
                btnOrder.Enabled = true;
                btnOrder.BackColor = Color.OliveDrab;
                btnOrder.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                lblInvalidDataWarning.Visible = false;
                MessageBox.Show("Looks good. Info ready to process!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("One or more of your informational data are incorrectly formatted and/or incomplete. Please correct and try again.");
                btnOrder.Enabled = false;
                btnOrder.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                btnOrder.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                lblInvalidDataWarning.Visible = true;
            }
        }

       public class Payment : Form1
        {
            //public Payment()
            //{
            //    grpOrderInfo.Refresh();
            //}
            string strSize = "";
            public string PizzaSize(string what)    // get pizza size and price. 'size' returns size, 'price' returns price.
                {
                    float price = 0.0f;

                    // Check pizza size selection
                    if (radSizeSmall.Checked)
                    {
                        strSize = "Small";
                        price += sngSmallPr;
                    }
                    else if (radSizeLrg.Checked)
                    {
                        strSize = "Large";
                        price += sngLrgPr;
                    }
                    else if (radSizeReg.Checked)
                    {
                        strSize = "Regular";
                        price += sngRegPr;
                    }

                    if (what == "size")
                    {
                        return strSize;
                    }
                    else if (what == "price")
                    {
                        return price.ToString(); // I don't want to have to convert the Single to a string just to return it
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return "ERROR: 'PizzaSize' can only return a 'size' or a 'price'!";
                    }
                }

            public float PizzaToppings()   //get pizza toppings and price
            {
                float topCount = 0;           //"topCount" is the total price of the toppings, which is later added to the total price, "sngPrice".
                float TopPr = 0;         // Total cost for toppings.
                //bool flag = false;          //Default: no toppings are choosen

                foreach (CheckBox c in grpOrderToppings.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()) // This is basically a for-loop that adds $1 for every "topping" serving checked.
                {                                                // TODO: Add special prices for certain toppings.
                    //CheckBox chkbox = c as CheckBox;
                    //c.Refresh();

                    if (c.Checked == true)
                    {
                        //flag = true;
                        topCount += 1;
                    }
                }

                TopPr = topCount;
                return TopPr;
            }

            public float CalcPay(BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
            {
                //RESET PRICE VALUES so that they don't add up when the user presses the "Price" button more than once.

                // By this point, a pizza size is selected and the user wants to check the price

                sngPrice += PizzaToppings(); //Add toppings price to pizza size price

                sngPrice += float.Parse(PizzaSize("price")); //get the price for the selected pizza size and add that to the price. 

                sngPrice = sngPrice * sngQuantity; // Multiply the price by the number of (DUPLICATE) pizzas

                lblSubtotalNum.Text = sngPrice.ToString("c"); //set subtotal label text for Price box
                lblSubtotalNum.Refresh();

                sngTax = 0.07f * sngPrice; //Sales tax is 7 percent of whatever the final price would've been otherwise.

                lblTaxNum.Text = sngTax.ToString("c"); //set Tax label text for Price box
                lblTaxNum.Refresh();

                sngPrice += sngTax;

                lblTotalNum.Text = sngPrice.ToString("c"); //set Total label text for Price box  
                lblTotalNum.Refresh();

                return sngPrice;
            }
        }



        private void chkTopHmb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void radSizeReg_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void chkTopHam_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkTopHam.Checked == true)
            {
                label1.Visible = true;
            }
        }

        private void grpOrderToppings_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void bindingSource1_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ttAccept_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: @Enigmativity helped me figure it out! The root of my problem lay in the creation of a new class to put the object-methods in, instead of just having the objects and their methods on their own object within the Form1 brackets. For some reason, the class wasn't inheriting the Form1 properties correctly, so all I had to do was delete the "Payment" class brackets and de-indent all the code that was in it, and now everything works! I was only calling Payment.CalcPay() with a constructor before; but now I can just say CalcPay() and that method was already prepared to do everything itself anyways.

Comment: What is this for: `CheckBox chkbox = c as CheckBox;`?. `foreach (CheckBox c in grpOrderToppings.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()) if (c.Checked) { topCount += 1; }` or `topCount += c.Checked ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: @Jimi I'm using "CheckBox chkbox = c as CheckBox;" (and subsequently, "chkbox.Checked") instead of the actual checkbox names because I have a lot of checkboxes in the group box, each with a unique name, so instead of having an if statement for each checkbox, I made a foreach statement that goes through every checkbox in the group box and (is supposed to) check their state. I know that this code is able to cycle through the checkboxes, but it can't properly get their properties, it would seem. The ".Checked" property always returns as false, regardless if it was actually checked.

Comment: Nothing here is dealing with controls' names. That cast is not useful. Test what I posted.

Comment: @Jimi OK I tried your code but it still isn't working. The .Checked property is still returning "false" for checked checkboxes.

Comment: You're possibly not *checking* the right collection of controls or the right container, then. Otherwise it would work.

Comment: @Jimi The groupbox name is spelled correctly. idk what's wrong

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the constructor of the form.  Good odds that you can now see that you create more than one instance of the class, one you look at and another you can't see and which you are debugging.

Comment: @HansPassant How do I fix that?

Comment: @MaxwellRyanFuller - You fix it by ensuring that you only create one instance of the form. Please post all of your code or delete this question.

Comment: @MaxwellRyanFuller - Why does `Payment` inherit from `Form`?

Comment: @Enigmativity The Payment class needs to inherit the variables/properties from Form in order for it to have access to the Checkboxes and other items on the form, otherwise it gives errors like "X does not exist in this context", etc

Comment: @MaxwellRyanFuller - No, `Payment` does not need to inherit `Form` - in fact, if it does you are probably doing something wrong. How are you providing `Payment` the form references? Your code doesn't show that?

Comment: @Enigmativity Without the " : Form1" at the end of "Payment", I get a bunch of errors: " CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.blah' "

Comment: @Enigmativity Do I need to make get-set methods for each Form1 object I use?

Comment: @MaxwellRyanFuller - Oh, I see now. I missed the `Form1` (I read it as `Form`). OK, but inheriting `Form1` you are effectively making a a fresh instance of all of the controls on `Form1` when you create `Payment`. They are not the same instances. That's what your issue is.

Comment: @MaxwellRyanFuller - So the question now is why you have a separate `Payment` class in the first place? Are you trying to separate your business logic from your user interface? Why not just have `string PizzaSize(string what)`, for example, as a method of `Form1`?

Comment: @Enigmativity I don't know why I separated the Payment class in the first place. I think it's because I like to have everything in one place. Well, I deleted the "public class Payment" code brackets, de-indented everything that was in it, AND NOW IT ACTUALLY WORKS! Thank you!!!

Comment: @MaxwellRyanFuller - It's a good idea to separate the logic. I've added an answer. I'd recommend you try my option 3, but it would be the hardest to get right for you now, however if you can do it you would become a far better programmer.

Comment: `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); // Don't forget to sleep!`  This is usually a bad sign.

Comment: @LarsTech - Yeah, I have no idea why that's there. There are a few things that need to be fixed that are probably worth thinking about longer term for the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your `Payment` class inherits from `Form1` you are defining a new class that contains all of the same elements as `Form1`, plus whatever you add to `Payment` itself`, but when you create an instance of`Payment`you are creating new instances of all of the controls. You are not referencing the elements of the`Form1`instance that you have already created. That's why the check boxes are not checked when you use the`Payment` form.

You have a few options here.

1. You could eliminate `Payment` as a separate class entirely and move the methods within `Payment` to simply be methods of `Form1`. That's the simplest approach, but it's not the best practice. Ideally if you have business logic you should try to separate it into another class, but you shouldn't allow any UI elements in to the class. That leads to 2.
2. Refactor your `Payment` class so that the methods take parameters of primitive types (not controls). For example, `string PizzaSize(string what, bool large, bool small, bool regular)`. But even better it would be useful to make your `Payment` class maintain state based on the input from the form. That leads to 3.
3. Create properties on `Payment` for all of the outputs - `Size`, `Price`, `Toppings`, `Pay`, etc - and have methods that you call based on the user actions - such as `LargeSelected`, `ToppingSelected(string topping)`, `ToppingRemoved(string topping)`, etc - thus removing all computation from `Form`.

There are other options, but those would be the main that I suggest at the moment.